# Error: Assignment makes pointer from Integer without a cast... in C Prog

Tags: c, pointers, casting, strtok

I get this error whenever i run the program " Assignment makes pointer from Integer without a cast". My code is written below.... Please help... Thankx

```
struct student {
       char studentID[6];
       char name[31];
       char course [6];
};
struct student *array[MAX];
struct student dummy;
int recordCtr=0;

int read(){
     FILE *stream = NULL;
     int ctr;
     char linebuffer[45];
     char delims[]=", ";
     char *number[3];
     char *token = NULL;

     stream = fopen("student.txt", "rt");

     if (stream == NULL) stream = fopen("student.txt", "wt");
     else {
          printf("\nReading the student list directory. Wait a moment please...");
          while(!feof(stream)){
                array[recordCtr]=(struct student*)malloc(sizeof(struct student)); 
                while(!feof(stream)) {
                     fgets(linebuffer, 46, stream);
                     token = strtok(linebuffer, delims); //This is where the error appears
                     ctr=0;
                     while(token != NULL){
                          strcpy(number[ctr], linebuffer);
                          token = strtok(NULL, delims);  //This is where the error appears
                          ctr++;
                     }
                     strcpy(array[recordCtr] -> studentID,number[0]);
                     strcpy(array[recordCtr] -> name,number[1]);  
                     strcpy(array[recordCtr] -> course,number[2]);                    

                }                     
          recordCtr++;
          }
     recordCtr--;
     fclose(stream);
     }
```

Comment: Sounds like you get the error when you COMPILE it, not when you RUN it. Also, can you tell us on what line you're getting it??

Comment: Yes... the error appears when i compile it... the line token = strtok(linebuffer, delims);

Comment: Where do you initialize this array `char *number[3];`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't (at least, not in the pasted code) `#include`d the header that defines the `strtok` function. In C, functions that haven't been prototyped yet are assumed to return `int`. Thus, we're assigning from an `int` (function result) to a `char*` (the type of `token`) without a cast.

We don't want a cast, of course. We want to `#include` the header, so that the compiler understands what `strtok` returns.

But we also don't really want to use `strtok` if there's anything else that will do the job. It has numerous limitations that aren't obvious. For robust string parsing, try `sscanf`.

Comment: Why the compiler does not throw "undefined reference to strtok" if the header has not been included ?

Comment: @n0p because of C's rules for implicit function declarations - see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816. It's different in C++ and you should expect to get an error - but also, using `strtok` is an **even worse** idea in C++. (Also: "undefined reference" errors come from the **linker**, not the compiler.)

Answer (score 1):

I think your`char *number[3];` should be `char number[3];`, or at least you should allocate space for each of the 3 `number` pointers.

Comment: No; the OP wants an array of three strings here, AFAICT. The problem is that `char*` is not a string; there is no space allocated for the data being copied with the `strcpy` call. But right now, the code doesn't even compile, so...

Comment: @Karl, this is exactly what I meant in my "at least" part of the answer.