# Message "warning: implicit declaration of function"

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

My compiler (GCC) is giving me the warning:

> warning: implicit declaration of function

Why is it coming?

Comment: A "why does it not give an error version": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434763/are-prototypes-required-for-all-functions-in-c89-c90-or-c99

Comment: This can also happen if you forget to include a header file. For example if you are trying to use strlen() without including string.h you will get this error

Comment: I think this question should be removed, as it clutters up every search for a specific instance of this warning. e.g. "My kernel stopped building today, let's see if others are having a similar issue..." Inevitably I end up here.

Answer (score 333, accepted):

You are using a function for which the compiler has not seen a declaration ("*prototype*") yet.

For example:

```
int main() {
    fun(2, "21"); /* The compiler has not seen the declaration. */       
    return 0;
}

int fun(int x, char *p) {
    /* ... */
}
```

You need to declare your function before main, like this, either directly or in a header:

```
int fun(int x, char *p);
```

Comment: As an addition if you have given the prototype check that it isn't just a typo. Also if its from an external library check that you have included it.

Comment: I cannot run the code after I get this warning. So it behaves like an error.

Comment: @Flimm, **C99** and **C89/C90** has different setting for this

Comment: @Flimm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434763/are-prototypes-required-for-all-functions-in-c89-c90-or-c99

Comment: C is a joke! Everything is done for you implicitly even when it makes absolutely no sense! Lots of warnings in C need to be errors for it to be any useful.

Comment: A prototype is a function declaration that specifies the types of any parameters. Not all function declarations are prototypes. (Arguably they all *should* be; non-prototype declarations are an obsolescent feature.)

Comment: @Flimm: In C99 and later, it's a *constraint violation*, which means that the standard requires a diagnostic. That diagnostic is not required to be fatal. Many C compilers take advantage of that and issue non-fatal warnings for many constraint violations. Most compilers have options to produce fatal errors, for example `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. The C standard never requires a program to be rejected unless it has a `#error` directive.

Comment: @ZachSaw: You need to pay attention to warnings, or use an option to turn them into fatal errors.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Hence "Lots of warnings in C need to be errors for it to be any useful."

Comment: @ZachSaw: Only if you don't pay attention to warnings. The C language standard doesn't distinguish between warnings and fatal errors (except for `#error`). If you're using gcc or clang, you can use `-pedantic-errors` or `-Werror`. Or you can just fix your code so it doesn't produce any warnings.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Again, hence "Lots of warnings in C need to be errors for it to be any useful."

Comment: @ZachSaw: I'm not sure what repeating your earlier statement is supposed to accomplish. If the fact that many diagnostics are non-fatal makes C useless to you, even after you've been offered advice on how to deal with it, I don't think I can help you.

Comment: @KeithThompson: In case it wasn't clear when I repeated it twice: you assumed I needed help.

Comment: @ZachSaw Rightly so. Else you would not have repeated yourself thrice.

Comment: You can also use static and not define it - but then this will cause fun to be see only in that specific file.

Answer (score 33):

The right way is to declare the function prototype in a header.

## Example

**main.h**

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

int some_main(const char *name);

#endif
```

**main.c**

```
#include "main.h"

int main()
{
    some_main("Hello, World\n");
}

int some_main(const char *name)
{
    printf("%s", name);
}
```

**Alternative with one file (main.c)**

```
static int some_main(const char *name);

int some_main(const char *name)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 12):

When you do your #includes in file *main.c*, add the #include reference to the file that contains the referenced function at the top of the include list.

E.g., say this is *main.c* and your referenced function is in file "SSD1306_LCD.h":

```
#include "SSD1306_LCD.h"
#include "system.h"        #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <libpic30.h>       // http://microchip.wikidot.com/faq:74
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "GenericTypeDefs.h"  // This has the 'BYTE' type definition
```

The above will not generate the "implicit declaration of function" error, but the below will:

```
#include "system.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <libpic30.h>       // http://microchip.wikidot.com/faq:74
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "GenericTypeDefs.h"     // This has the 'BYTE' type definition
#include "SSD1306_LCD.h"
```

Exactly the same #include list, just a different order.

Well, it did for me.

Comment: Why two includes in one line? - `#include "system.h"  #include <stdio.h>`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare the desired function before your **main** function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int yourfunc(void);

int main(void) {

   yourfunc();
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

When you get the *"error: implicit declaration of function"*, it should also list the offending function.

Often this error happens because of a forgotten or missing header file, so at the shell prompt you can type `man 2 functionname` and look at the `SYNOPSIS` section at the top, as this section will list any header files that need to be included. Or try *[man](http://linux.die.net/man/)*. Those are the online *man* pages. They are hyperlinked and easy to search.

Functions are often defined in the header files, including any required header files is often the answer. Like [cnicutar said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/message-warning-implicit-declaration-of-function/8440833#8440833),

> You are using a function for which the compiler has not seen a
> declaration ("prototype") yet.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget, if any functions are called in your function, their prototypes must be situated above your function in the code. Otherwise, the compiler might not find them before it attempts to compile your function. This will generate the error in question.

Comment: Does this add anything not already provided by the other answers?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the correct headers defined & are using a non [glibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library) library (such as [Musl C](http://musl.libc.org/)), GCC will also throw *"error: implicit declaration of function"* when GNU extensions such as `malloc_trim` are encountered.

The solution is to [wrap the extension & the header](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/blob/master/testing/kid3/musl.patch):

```
#if defined (__GLIBC__)
  malloc_trim(0);
#endif
```

Comment: The first link is half broken. The second link is completely broken (*"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at patchwork.alpinelinux.org."*).

Comment: Alpine uses Gitlab nowadays - links updated

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because you are trying to use a function that the compiler does not understand. If the function you are trying to use is predefined in C language, just include a header file associated with the implicit function.
If it's not a predefined function then it's always a good practice to declare the function before the main function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is not 100% answered. I was searching for an issue with a missing typeof(), which is a compile-time directive.

The following links will shine light on the situation:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Typeof.html

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html#Alternate-Keywords

As of a conclusion, try to use `__typeof__()` instead. Also `gcc ... -Dtypeof=__typeof__ ...` can help.

Comment: The first reference says *"If you are writing a header file that must work when included in ISO C programs, write `__typeof__` instead of `typeof`. "*

Answer (score 0):

The GNU C compiler is telling you that it can find that particular function name in the program scope. Try defining it as a private prototype function in your header file, and then import it into your main file.

Comment: Re *"...it can find"*: Don't you mean *"...it can’t find"* (the opposite)?