# Implicit declaration of functions srand, rand and system

Tags: c, linux, random, system, srand

Trying to solve an exercise where I have to print a random temperature value between 35°C & -10°C every 5 seconds followed by the date and time. Everything looks to be working as intended, however when I enter the code in a test script I get following errors.

[image: implicit declaration of functions errors]
This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>
#define temp_max 35
#define temp_min -10
#define FREQUENCY 5

int main(void)
{
srand(time(NULL));
while(1)
{
int number = rand() % (temp_max*100 - temp_min*100) + temp_min*100;
double temperature = (double) number;
temperature /= 100;
printf("Temperature=%1.2f @ ",temperature);
fflush(stdout); 
system("date");
sleep(FREQUENCY);
}
return 0;
}
```

These are my results:

[image: These are my results]

This is what the test script checks for:

[image: This is what the test script checks for]

As I am unable to see my own mistakes, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you searched your error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function

Comment: I have but I didn't seem to find anything that related to my problem..

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You failed to `#include <stdlib.h>`.  As a result, the functions you called were assumed to accept an unknown number of arguments and return a value of type `int`.  This causes undefined behavior.

Put `#include <stdlib.h>` at the top of your file.

Comment: Is it normal that my script is able to run while I forgot this include? I always assumed that the script wouldn't even have ran if this was the problem..

Comment: @TheAlPaca02 The program will still compile with the mismatched signature.  If the parameters are not of the correct type however, the compiler won't be able to detect it.

Comment: Ok understood, thanks! Will run the testscript again tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My code was compiled but I got warning message.

```
// Selection sort

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int list[100], i;

    for(i = 0 ; i < 100; i++) {
        list[i] = ( rand()%99 + 1 );
        printf("%d ", list[i]);
    } printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it,

```
gcc -o selection_sort selection_sort.c -lm
selection_sort.c: In function ‘main’:
selection_sort.c:11:15: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rand’; did you mean ‘nanl’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
list[i] = ( rand()%99 + 1 );
           ^~~~
           nanl
```

After adding `<stdlib.h>` warning message was gone.

Comment: So basically you are saying that the other answer solved your problem? You don't need to post another answer to say that the other answer is good -- you can simply upvote the other answer