# Producer Consumer Solution

Tags: c, malloc

I've developed the producer / consumer problem in C and for some reason it doesn't compile. I'm getting the error message:

```
 try1.c: In function ‘main’:

try1.c:19:21: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]

       BUFFER=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * BufferSize);
```

Please could someone identify the issue? Have tried for a while to fix this now however haven't had any luck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define BufferSize 10

void *Producer();
void *Consumer();

int BufferIndex=0;
char *BUFFER;

pthread_cond_t Buffer_Not_Full=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t Buffer_Not_Empty=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mVar=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main()
{    
    pthread_t ptid,ctid;

    BUFFER=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * BufferSize);            

    pthread_create(&ptid,NULL,Producer,NULL);
    pthread_create(&ctid,NULL,Consumer,NULL);

    pthread_join(ptid,NULL);
    pthread_join(ctid,NULL);


    return 0;
}

void *Producer()
{    
    for(;;)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mVar);
        if(BufferIndex==BufferSize)
        {                        
            pthread_cond_wait(&Buffer_Not_Full,&mVar);
        }                        
        BUFFER[BufferIndex++]='@';
         printf("Produce : %d \n",BufferIndex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mVar);
        pthread_cond_signal(&Buffer_Not_Empty);        
    }    

}

void *Consumer()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mVar);
        if(BufferIndex==-1)
         {            
             pthread_cond_wait(&Buffer_Not_Empty,&mVar);
         }                
        printf("Consume : %d \n",BufferIndex--);        
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mVar);        
        pthread_cond_signal(&Buffer_Not_Full);                
    }    
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: That is not an error, but a warning. That won't prevent the code from compiling.

Comment: A malloc with a cast, and yet the warning is still there. How interesting...

Comment: Add `#include  <malloc.h>` to removing the warning.

Comment: You need to `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: That is not an error, but a warning. But you are right not to try to execute code after you got a warning. Use `-Werror` to ensure that.

Comment: @2501 it's a different warning, though :)

Comment: The function prototype that you want to run as a thread should be  `void *Consumer(void *)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: implicit declaration of function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function)

Comment: You are misusing `pthread_cond_wait()`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this question has nothing to do with producer/consumer. It has to do with the use of a function you didn't declare.

Historically, C allowed calling a function which was never declared. Since technically function declaration is not needed to call it, compiler gladly added instructions to call the unknown function. Allegedly, it allowed developers to save precious keystrokes. However, you need a function declaration to know it's return value, and compiler assumed that return value of such a function is `int`. And you are having just that - an implicitly declared `malloc()` with assumed return type of `int`.

Now, compiler **knows** what `malloc()` is. It is often built-in intrinstic function. However, compiler also knows that return value of said `malloc()` is `void*`, not `int` - and thus it complains.

Solution - get rid of implicit declaration, and make a habit of always including apropriate header files for every function you are using.

You also have issues with the way you are using conditional variables, but I would leave it for another question.

Answer (score 1):

The producer should go to sleep when the buffer is full. Next time when the consumer removes data it notifies the producer and producer start producing data again. The consumer should go to sleep when a buffer is empty. Next time when producer adds data it notifies the consumer and consumer starts consuming data. This solution can be achieved using semaphores.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
int mutex=1,full=0,empty=3,x=0;

int main()
{
    int n;
    void producer(void);
    void consumer(void);
    int waiting(int);
    int signaling(int);
    printf("\n1.Producer\n2.Consumer\n3.Exit");
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter your choice:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        switch(n)
        {
            case 1: if((mutex==1)&&(empty!=0))
                producer();
            else
                printf("Buffer is full!!");
                break;
            case 2:    if((mutex==1)&&(full!=0))
                consumer();
            else
                printf("Buffer is empty!!");
                break;
            case 3:
                exit(0);
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int waiting(int s)
{
    return (--s);
}

int signaling(int s)
{
    return(++s);
}

void producer()
{
    mutex=wait(&mutex);
    full=signaling(full);
    empty=wait(&empty);
    x++;
    printf("\nProducer produces the item %d",x);
    mutex=signaling(mutex);
}

void consumer()
{
    mutex=wait(&mutex);
    full=wait(&full);
    empty=signaling(empty);
    printf("\nConsumer consumes item %d",x);
    x--;
    mutex=signaling(mutex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include the stdlib.h library. This library will include the malloc() function.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `malloc` without including the header file that declares it (stdlib.h).

Your usage (without that explicit declaration from stdlib.h) creates an "implicit declaration" which doesn't match the one the compiler knows about because yours returns `char*` and the proper `malloc` returns `void*`.

So add `include <stdlib.h>` and also note that you shouldn't cast the result of a malloc. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Correct up to the point of `doesn't match the one the compiler knows about ... ` - than incorrect :)

Comment: You just said in your own answer that the "compiler knows what malloc is". How else can it complain "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’" when the `malloc` function hasn't been declared?

Comment: I did. And I stand by my answer and my comment. Hint - the idea that compiler knows about malloc is correct. It is the *return type* of it part which is incorrect. Read my answer to see the correct one.

Comment: Okay, I see. I thought the compiler was allowed to derive the return type of the implicit declaration from the context. But it seems not. Thanks for the correction. The point about not casting the result of `malloc` remains though.

Comment: I am a strong proponent of not casting return type of malloc myself :)