# Why is "implicit declaration of function" just a warning?

Tags: c, compilation, warnings, compiler-warnings, linkage

This is NOT a question on how to resolve the "implicit declaration of function" warnings that appear in C programs, that has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function) many times already.

I understand that this is a compiler warning, what I'm wondering is why is this a warning rather than an error? If the compiler cannot see the function, what happens when the function is called at runtime? Does the linker ultimately resolve this issue? Or are we to assume that the behaviour of calling a function that produced such warning is unknown?

Comment: You're to assume that the function can take any number or type of arguments and return an `int`. At least, that's what the compiler does. This may be removed in future versions of the specification.

Comment: The implicit `int` rule is no longer in the standard... but may still work as an extension.  I don't think there's anything in the current standard that says the compiler *can't* assume an `int` return, it's just not required to anymore (and should issue a diagnostic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is this a warning rather than an error?

Because there are a lot of legacy code thet is written in such way. Compiler error will break it.

> If the compiler cannot see the function, what happens when the function is called at runtime? Does the linker ultimately resolve this issue?

Let's look the example:

```
int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

When working the compiler generates its own function signature like `int foo(...)` and will use it. By the way it can lead to very curious errors. So the object file will contain the call of this function and it is ok. When you will try to link it you will get an error: undefined reference to `foo'. But if you have another module with `foo` definition, the linker will find it by name and link it.

> Or are we to assume that the behaviour of calling a function that
>   produced such warning is unknown?

As I said it can lead to some curious errors. Imagine that you have code like `int i = foo()` and `foo` is without signature. And in another module you have the following: `int * foo(){...}`. When building application in 64 bit mode you will put to `i` only 32 bit of a 64 bit pointer. So you may say in fact the behaviour of your program may be unknown.

Answer (score 2):

Because of harmful traditions carried forward by mainstream compilers, including the one you're using. Thankfully they usually have options to make it an error, like `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` for gcc and compatible compilers.

Answer (score 0):

The standard places very few requirements on an implementation regarding diagnostics:

> **5.1.1.3 Diagnostics**
> 1     A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined. Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances.<sup>9)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>9) The intent is that an implementation should identify the nature of, and where possible localize, each violation. Of course, an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a valid program is still correctly translated. It may also successfully translate an invalid program.</sup>

Comment: This answer also explains why compilers emit warnings (and not errors) for references to undefined global variables... even though they don't.