# C - Passing string in a function in a thread and returning it results in a non-existant, non-printable string?

Tags: c, string, function

Inside a thread, I run this function:

```
char *r = NetString("ch","aaaaa");
printf("%s",r); printf("%s","\n");
```

Which calls

```
char *NetString(char *id, char *data) {
  char *result;
  result = (char *)malloc(strlen(id)+strlen(data)+2);
  strcpy(result, id);
  strcat(result, "/");
  strcat(result, data);
  printf("%s",result); printf("%s","\n");
  return (char *)result;
}
```

In the console, when I compile this warning shows up:

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
[enabled by default]: char *r = NetString("ch","aaaaa");
                                ^
```

If you need the full code (which may be a bit unorganized), here it is:
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/M38uFLbQ)

Apparently, this code runs as expected (returns "ch/aaaaa" twice) when not run in a thread, but when I run it in a thread, the string only prints once (that is, in the NetString function). Any help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: My guess is return in NetString finishes off your thread. But I am not sure.

Comment: always check the return value of malloc

Comment: and don't cast the return of malloc

Comment: do you run Netstring as a thread or is the call to Netstring in a thread?

Comment: If you understood how `strcat()` works you would never use it consecutively, specially if you already used `strlen()` with the components. Also, there is no guarantee that `id` or `data` are `nul` terminated because you did not post the code that initializes them. Finally casting `void *` to `char *` is not necessary but casting `char *` to `char *` indicates that something is wrong in your code.

Comment: In short, the lack of context in your example does not help in finding out the problem.

Comment: @TonyTannous I believe the thread keeps running, strings after that get printed correctly, it's just not the "r" one.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi id and data are initialized in the NetString("ch","aaaaa") line... right? Also I removed both (char *) casts, no additional errors showed up.

Comment: Can you show how is the whole program running?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi added full code link in my question: http://pastebin.com/M38uFLbQ

Comment: The warning says that you forgot to declare NetString properly. Enable all warnings and treat them as errors (-Wall -Wextra -Werror). Saves all of us time.

Comment: @n.m. to be fair it doesn't say exactly that (there's [another warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function) for that one), but it does hint strongly at the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
char *r = NetString("ch","aaaaa");
```

and this error

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
[enabled by default]: char *r = NetString("ch","aaaaa");
                                ^
```

almost certainly mean:

1. You are calling `NetString()` without providing a function prototype, thus it is treated as returning `int`.
2. You are running on a 64-bit platform where pointers are 64 bit and `int` values are 32 bit.

Thus, your `char *` pointer value from `NetString()` gets truncated to an `int`, then assigned to a pointer, where it no longer points to anything useful.

You need to provide a proper prototype with a function declaration:

```
char *NetString( char *, char * );
```

in all code that calls `NetString()`, and the prototype needs to be *before* any such calls.