# BlueZ 5.43: D-BUS gattlib ble_scan

Tags: c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am developping a BLE application and I need to implement a function for discovering advertising BLE devices.

I inspired my code from the [gattlib project](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/), but i can't understand the following functions starting with "org_bluez_"  such as :'org_bluez_adapter1_proxy_new_for_bus_sync' , 'org_bluez_device1_proxy_new_for_bus_sync',...

I tried to google it but i didn't find a thing that could help , so please can anyone help me understand!

Comment: You should [search for the generic warning](https://www.google.de/search?q=warning:+implicit+declaration+of+function), not for the function name specific to your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: implicit declaration of function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function)

Comment: in fact am using to solve that problem with simply defining the function and that's what i tried to do but i searched in the whole project i inspired my code from and there was no definition of such a function

Answer (score 0):

Here is the author of [gattlib](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/). Any reason why duplicating the library and not using the library itself?

To answer your question these functions are from the auto-generated code produced from the XML definition of the bluez D-BUS API.