# Why am I unable to store the return value of the function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variable-assignment

I am trying to return the value of a string from another function and store it as a variable. This is what I have written but I am having trouble resolving the issue.

```
#include "stdio.h"

void main() 
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    char result[60];
    result = menuFunction();
}

const char* menuFunction() 
{
    return "Hello Again";
}
```

Comment: `result = menuFunction();`...compiler did not tell you anything?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function
you need to switch the order of declaration

Comment: Use `#include <stdio.h>`.  Note [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) too.

Comment: `char result[60];` --> `const char *result;`

Comment: *"...but I am having trouble resolving the issue"* What issue?

Comment: Another approach: `result = menuFunction();` -> `strcpy(result, menuFunction())`. That will copy the "Hello Again" into `result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `result` is array type, which is not a modifiable lvalue, hence cannot be used as LHS of assignment operator.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.16

> An assignment operator shall have a **modifiable lvalue as its left operand.**

and chapter §6.3.2.1, (*emphasis mine*)

> **An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially
>   designates an object;** <sup>64)</sup> if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the
>   behavior is undefined. When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is
>   specified by the lvalue used to designate the object. **A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that
>   does not have array type**, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified
>   type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including,
>   recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified
>   type.

**Solution:** Define `result` as a pointer instead.

That said,

- for a hosted environment, `void main()` is pretty much disallowed. You should be using `int main(void)` to conform to the standard.
- using a function (call) before the function definition or a [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) in place, is also disallowed. You need to define the function beforehand or have a forward declaration of the same before you use it.