# Implicit declaration of function 'xmlFree' is invalid in C99

Tags: ios, objective-c

We use WSDLParser tool to parse our xml content, till Xcode 9.2 everything was ok. As we shifted to Xcode 9.3, we are getting this error in one of parser file "Implicit declaration of function 'xmlFree' is invalid in C99".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: implicit declaration of function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function)

Comment: Are you sure you've `#include`d or `#import`ed the relevant header files?

Comment: yes..but i'm getting this error after updated Xcode 9.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration was moved to globals.h, it should compile with this import:

```
#import <libxml/globals.h>
```

Comment: I tried this code. but now it shows error message invalid bitcode signature. How to solve it?