# implicit declaration warning when trying getting home directory

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, home-directory

I type this code to get the home directory. I have later edited it to include all of the code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "anotherfile.h"

typedef unsigned int uint;

void Interval(void) {
    static uint S = 0;
    static uint C = 0;
    static uint M = 0;
    static uint D = 0;
    usleep(10e5/0x20);
    printf("%d\n", C);
    printf("%d\n", S);
    printf("%d\n", M);
    if(C == 0x20) {
        if(S == 59) {
            S=0;
            M++;
        }else{S++;}
        C=0;
    }else{C++;}
    Interval();
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char *HomeDir;
    if((HomeDir = getenv("HOME")) == NULL) {
        HomeDir = getpwuid(getuid())->pw_dir;
        if(HomeDir == NULL) {
            printf("Failed to get Home Directory\n");
        }else{printf("Retry Home Directory Found\n");}
    }else{printf("Success getting Home Directory\n");}
    Interval();
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me the implicit declaration warning. It says something is wong with the `getenv` partHow can I fix it?

Comment: You need to include `<unistd.h>`

Comment: In my real program I did, I forgot to add it to my question

Comment: Please always post the code you are actually compiling. With the new code I can't reproduce the problem, what does your compiler exactly say?

Comment: @Osiris I am sorry.

Comment: It's no problem. What is the exact line the compiler outputs? On which platform are you working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: implicit declaration of function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function)

Comment: linux, but what do you mean by which line does the compiler output?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver That's not a helpful question. He's calling a function that should be declared in a header that he's included.

Comment: The whole warning the compiler outputs could be helpful for us.

Comment: Try putting `#define _POSIX_SOURCE` before all the `#include`s.

Comment: please answer my q

Comment: As said we need the whole warning the compiler outputs, for example before including `unistd.h` i got `<source>:10:28: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getuid'; did you mean 'getpwuid'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Comment: @JulianTiemann i cant reproduce it: `~/code$ gcc -Wall -Wimplicit-function-declaration test.c -o test
~/code$ ./test 
Tried again, Home Directory Found!`

Comment: Is there any more code missing from the post? The message `printf("Tried again, Home Directory Found!\n");` appears to be in the wrong code block, since in its position there was only one attempt. The repeat attempt is in the code block above, which doesn't print anything on success.

Comment: I made a mistake

Comment: EVERYONE I OMMITED SOME CODE BECAUSE I THOUGHT IT WOULD CAUSE CONFUSION!

Comment: I LATER EDITED IT TO bE COMPLETE!

Comment: But now `stdlib.h` is missing where `getenv` is defined, which was included in your previous code.

Comment: @Osiris thx that solved my problem post that as an answer and it will be accepted

Comment: A general rule to follow: before using *any* library function, read its documentation to find out what header declares it, and the types and meanings of its parameters and return value. Also, when posting a question, don't just describe the error message, copy-and-paste the message into your question, formatted as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getenv` is declared in `stdlib.h` according to [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getenv.html) reference. So you need to add

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: IT WORKED! THANK YOU!