# How to call main from external functions file

Tags: c

Gcc gives the error "functions.c: In function 'retryop':
functions.c:109:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'main' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
main();
^~~~"

I'm creating a function that calls back to main to restart the file, but i don't know how to have it return since main is declared after my functions file. Any help with this would be very greatly appreciated.

Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "functions.c"

int main()
{
setup();

char type;
double number1;
double number2;
int temp;
bool retry;

printf("Please choose what operation you would like to do  ( +, -, *,/, or R): \n");
scanf("%c", &type);

if (type == '+')
{
    setup();

    printf("Addition\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("Please enter Addend 1:");
    scanf("%lf", &number1);

    printf("Please enter Addend 2:");
    scanf("%lf", &number2);

    double answer = number1 + number2;

    printf("The Sum is: %f", answer);

    retryop();
}
else if (type == '-')
{
    setup();

    printf("Subtraction\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("Please enter Your Minuend:");
    scanf("%lf", &number1);

    printf("Please enter Your Subtrahend:");
    scanf("%lf", &number2);

    double answer = number1 - number2;

    printf("The Differnce is: %f", answer);

    retryop();
}
else if (type == '*')
{
    setup();

    printf("Muliplication\n");
    printf("\n");
    
    printf("Please enter Factor 1:");
    scanf("%lf", &number1);

    printf("Please enter Factor 2:");
    scanf("%lf", &number2);

    double answer = number1 * number2;

    printf("Your Product is: %f", answer);

    retryop();
}
else if (type == '/')
{
    setup();

    printf("Division\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("Please enter your divadend:");
    scanf("%lf", &number1);

    printf("Please enter your divisor:");
    scanf("%lf", &number2);

    double answer = number1 / number2;

    printf("Your quotient is: %f", answer);

    retryop();
}
else if (type == 'R')
{
    setup();

    int maxValue;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Please enter your max value:");
    scanf("%i", &maxValue);
    int random = (rand() % (maxValue + 1));
    printf("Here is your random number: %i", random);

    retryop();
}
else if (type == 'r')
{
    setup();

    int maxValue;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Please enter your max value:");
    scanf("%i", &maxValue);
    int random = (rand() % (maxValue + 1));
    printf("Here is your random number: %i\n", random);

    retryop();
}
else
{
    setup();

    printf("Please Re-run your program and enter a valid Operator\n");
    system("pause");
    Main();
}
}
```

Functions.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char type;
double number1;
double number2;
double answer;
bool retry;
char temp;

void setup()
{
system("cls");
}

int typeselect()
{
printf("Please choose what operation you would like to do  ( +, -, *,/, or R): \n");
scanf("%c", &type);

return type;
}

int retryop()
{
printf("Would you like to do this again? [Y/N]");
scanf("%i", &temp);
if (temp == 'Y')
{
    system("pause");
    Main();
}
else if (temp == 'y')
{
    system("pause");
    Main();
}

else if(temp == 'N')
{
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
else if(temp == 'n')
{
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
else
{
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Don't code everything in the main.

Comment: `main()` is different than `Main()`

Comment: @Cid  I fixed that, and it still gives the exact same error

Comment: Repeat, don't code everything in `main`. Write seperate function(s) for that. And more generally, functions need to be declared before they are used, see: [warning: implicit declaration of function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function)

Comment: Well, you have not declared `main()` in `functions.c`

Answer (score 2):

Functions should be declared before they are used, and `main` is no exception. Old versions of C would declare functions implicitly when they were called, and some compilers still allow this, but it is bad practice.

First, in main.c, define `main` properly, using `int main(void)`. Avoid using `int main()`; it is better to explicitly state `main` is being used with no arguments, if that is how you are using it. (You can also use `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` if you are using the arguments passed to it.)

Then, in Functions.c, declare `main` the same way: `int main(void);`. You can put this line directly in Functions.c or put it in a header file such as `main.h`, which should be included with an `#include` statement in both main.c and Functions.c.

That said, having `retryop` call `main` the way you do is bad design. The code for retrying should be designed as a loop that repeats if a retry is necessary, not as recursive calls to `main`.

Comment: Calling `main()` recursively is almost invariably a (very) bad idea, even though C allows it.  Note that C++ does not allow `main()` to be called recursively.