# pass the sum by pointer, generates output error

Tags: c

I have the following simple code in C:

```
void main()
{
    int* s;
    int a = 5, b = 3;
    sum(a, b, s);
    printf("%d + %d = %d", a, b, *s);
}
void sum(int a, int b, int* s) {
    *s = a + b;
}
```

the program compiles, but gives a runtime error. Why?

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 0.972 s
> Press any key to continue.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you told us *which* runtime error...

Comment: Hint: where does `s` point?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, edited

Comment: @dbush: "s" is used only to display the sum

Comment: @Serge Yes, but what is it pointing to?

Comment: @dbush, what is the difference, where does it point? the important part that to that adress is assigned the sum of a and b

Comment: @Serge, it does matter.  The line `*s = a+b;` means, "Store the value of `a+b` into the integer whose address is contained in `s`."  However, there **is no such integer**.

Comment: @Serge Pointers have to point somewhere, and `s` was never assigned any address.

Comment: @dbush, so, where is pointing a never assigned pointer, if they "have to point somewhere"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, avoid [implicit function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sum(int a, int b, int* s);

void main()
{
    int s;
    int a = 5, b = 3;
    sum(a, b, &s);
    printf("%d + %d = %d", a, b, s);
}

void sum(int a, int b, int* s) {
    *s = a + b;
    return;
}
```

This prints 8. If you still wish to use `int* s` then allocate space for a single int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sum(int a, int b, int* s);

void main()
{
    int* s = malloc(sizeof(int)*1);
    int a = 5, b = 3;
    sum(a, b, s);
    printf("%d + %d = %d", a, b, *s);
}
```

This will also print 8.

Comment: how you pass to the fucntion an int, s, when you have to pass an "int *"?

Comment: @Serge I didn't pass an int. I passed `&s` which is the address of an int. ----  `int* s` is a pointer to int. It stores the address of int (that's how it points...), by passing `&s` I am passing the address of `s` which is an address of an int.

Comment: ok, so, the compiler is not smart enough to do the malloc for me?

Comment: @Serge I'm offended on behalf of the compiler. Remember, the compiler has no way to tell how much memory you may want to allocate. In your case it's a single `int` but it could have been a block of 1000 ints...

Comment: thanks now I understand ) I used your second version, that is good for me

Comment: @Serge don't forget to include stdlib. I forgot to paste it. Let me edit.

Comment: however, I don't really like the compiler... It could automatically realocate memory if I would assign 1000 ints instead of one....

Comment: @Serge maybe you should try [tag:c++] then. It has self-adapting containers doing the allocation on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

`s` is an `int*` which means that it **can** store the address of an `int`.  However, you never made it do so.  Therefore, when `sum` dereferences it, you're dereferencing an invalid address (i.e., whatever junk stack data `s` was assigned when `main` began).

You need to do something like

```
int main() {
    int a, b, c;

    a=5;
    b=3;

    sum(a,b,&c);
    printf("%d + %d = %d", a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you want to use an `int*` variable,

```
int main() {
    int *s;
    int a, b, c;

    a=5;
    b=3;
    s=&c;

    sum(a,b,s);
    printf("%d + %d = %d", a, b, *s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand... suppose int* s is pointing to a random location in the memory. Why does this random location value does not change to a+b in the "sum" function?

Comment: Because that's not what `*s=a+b;` does.  That command instead stores the value of `a+b` into the integer whose address is stored in `s`.  There is no such integer.

Comment: @Serge You may dereference a pointer that points to a valid object.

Comment: If you want to change the value of `s`, you need to do something like `s = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

```c
int* s;
```

Here you're creating a pointer to int. But if you haven't located any memory for the int yet.

A possible solution would be to declare the same way you did with `a` and `b`, and then pass its reference to the function.

```c
void main()
{
    int s;
    int a = 5, b = 3;
    sum(a, b, &s);
    printf("%d + %d = %d", a, b, s);
}
void sum(int a, int b, int* s) {
    *s = a + b;
}
```