# Why don't I have "undefined reference to"?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker, undefined-reference

I faced a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330682) in my (big) project.

```
//# include <string.h> // not included

void foo(char * str, const char * delim)
{
    char * tok = strtok(str, delim); 
    // warning ^ "assignement makes pointer from integer without a cast"

    // [...]
}
```

The answer (just add `#include <string.h>` to have the prototype of `strtok`) solved the issue indeed.

However, due to my poor compiler/linker knowledge, I fail to understand how the process accepts a function that have not been prototyped.
I'd rather expected the error `undefined reference to function 'strtok'` which is typical when you forget to include the right header.

[EDIT] I understand why this question has been marked as duplicate but I do think it is different : I am aware of "good practice" regarding includes, I am just wondering about compiler's behavior. However I admit that I can found (part of) an answer to my question in this post: [Are prototypes required for all functions in C89, C90 or C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434763) or this one: [Must declare function prototype in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575153)

Comment: Short answer: You will get an error if you compile the code as C99 or later.  Add the gcc flag `-std=c11` or `-std=c99`.

Comment: The compiler never will "throw" (whatever that means) or report such an error. That is the linker. And regardless of the "must": you definitively **should**. Any halfway modern coding standard of the last 20 years requires that.

Comment: @Olaf Fixed (this is already a clue about the answer to my post actually).
Any chance to revert the "duplicate" mark following my edit ?

Comment: I don't see this is **not** a dup, so I will not vote to re-open. If you want to know more about that in detail, just read the standard or a good C book, (on this subject **only** an older one might even be better). Otherwise just enable warnings, use a modern C compiler which supports **at least** C99 so you get warnings, enable all other recommended warnings and ... **use prototypes!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While *linking* your binary, unless explicitly mentioned, your binary is linked with the default C standard library (`glibc`, for example) anyways, where the function is *defined*.

So, when you miss the header file containing the *declaration*, you end up with the *warning* (in case the function prototype has a mismatch<sup>note</sup>) but during linking time, due to the presence of the default C library, the program is successfully linked *anyway*.

FWIW, according to `C11`, support for implicit function declaration has been dropped but most compilers support the *bad* behavior to keep the backward compatibility for the legacy code.

---

NOTE:

*Implicit function declaration:* Earlier, (before C99, AFAIK), the standard did not mandate for a function to have the forward declaration. In case, a function would have been used without a forward declaration, it was assumed to return `int` and accept any number of incoming parameters.

Comment: I'd say "*bad* behavior" is a bit strong - it's *different* behavior.  With legacy code, not requiring prototypes is a critical language feature because it's not safe to just add prototypes for functions that were coded without them as function arguments are treated differently - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls

Comment: @AndrewHenle Sorry, but I did not get the point. Isn't there variadic functions to achieve the same while conforming to the standard? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Because gcc automatically links your code with the C library. The "undefined reference to function" error is typically issued by the *linker* when it couldn't resolve a symbol and that only occurs if the symbol couldn't be found in any of the libraries linked (the order of linking might also matter). But the C library is linked by default -- it's as if you linked it with `-lc`. So, you don't get that error.

If you tell gcc to *not* link the C library using `-nostdlib` then you'll see the error you expected:

```
$ gcc -nostdlib file.c
```

On the other hand, you should always provide prototypes for functions.

You may be interested in other similar linker options such as `-nodefaultlibs`, `nostartfiles` etc which you can find in [gcc's manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).