# Getting this error: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


    int main(int argc, char** argv){
            struct Node *hashtable[1000000];
            struct Node *starting=NULL;

            if(argc!=2){
                    return 0;
            }

            FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

            if(file==NULL){
                    printf("error\n");
                    return 0;
            }

            int j;

            for(j=0; j<1000000;j++){
                    hashtable[j]=NULL;
            }

            char user;
            int value;
            int k;

            while(fscanf(file,"%c %d\n", &user, &value)==2){
                    if(value>=0){
                            k=(value%1000000);
                    }else{
                            k=-(value%1000000);
                    }

                    if(user=='i'){
                            if(hashtable[k]!=NULL){
                                    struct Node *temp=hashtable[k];
                                    hashtable[k]=insertNew(temp,value);
                            } else{
                                    hashtable[k]=insertNew(starting,value);
                            }
                    }
```

There are more methods being used, but I am getting the following error:

third.c:86:45: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
                                 hashtable[k]=insertNew(temp,value);
                                             ^
third.c:88:45: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
                                 hashtable[k]=insertNew(starting,value);

I understand what this means, but I am confused as to why I am getting this error here...

Comment: If `insertNew` is in the same compilation unit you would get a compiler **error** too, because of mis-matching types. The linker is not so rigorous.

Comment: @WeatherVane: This is not a linker-warning.

Comment: @alk I know. But with the function in a different compilation unit there is no error - just saying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Assignment makes pointer from Integer without a cast... in C Prog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330682/error-assignment-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-a-cast-in-c-prog)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a prototype for `insertNew()` so your compiler is assuming it's a prototype-less function returning `int`.

You should be including a header with the prototype of `insertNew()` at the top or declare the prototype at the top of your file manually.